# Laravel5 pagination with Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel5 pagination. I have added some ajax code because when I click next button I don't need to refresh the page.

My issue is when I am clicking next button my page is refreshing. please help me to find this issue. My code and screen shot are given below.

In firefox firebug console showing some error "TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getDefaultComputedStyle is not an object."

**js**
**#abilitytest: Click function for showing data in bootstrap model**

```
$( "#abilitytest" ).click(function() {
    $.post("/abilitytest", function(response){
        $( "#abilityQuestions" ).html(response);
    });
});


$('.pagination a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(page);
    alert('hai');
});
```

**Controller**

```
$abilitytests = Abilitytest::simplePaginate(1);
return view('test.abilitytestmodal',['abilitytests' => $abilitytests]);
```

[image]

Comment: Is `.pagination a` an element inside `#abilityQuestions` ? Is `#abilitytest` an `<a>` tag? Are you seeing your `console.log` or `alert` at all? The mentioned TypeError does not seem related to the code you posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I am using laravel pagination built-in function `simplePaginate()`.

`Abilitytest::simplePaginate(1)` the ul class of pagination will be class="pager".`<ul class="pager">`.

If we are using laravel built-in function `paginate()` the ul class of pagination will be class="pagination"..

So the issue is I am using wrong class name in JS file "`<ul class="pagination">`".

So  my code is

```
$('.pager a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(page);
    alert('hai');
});
```

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there some trouble with binding event listener on `$('.pagination a')`?

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event){
```

Instead of

```
$('.pagination a').on('click', function (event) {
```

Comment: @samsam Check out the edited post. I feel like you may have tried to implement it wrongly.

Answer (score -6):

you can use jQuery on document ready like this

`$(document).ready(function (){
$('.pagination a').on('click', function (event) {`

Comment: yeah because i did an example

Comment: Your answer does not seem relevant to OP's problem.

Comment: it is, you just have to finish and its not so hard but apparently here people need all the code, they want to you write all code and they say thanks its not coding in this case its just take and copy

Comment: Disregarding what Yummy said, I don't see how your `$(document).ready()` would fix the problem. As I understand, it's not the Ajax call itself that is causing the problem.

Comment: ok may be he dont but it's just another way to do this without problem

Comment: If the problem is caused by wrong event binding, then your piece of code would still give the exact same issue. If you think your code may solve the problem, please explain in your answer why, so everyone can understand.

Comment: i'm new on stackoverflow so i dont think in first they need all explain but you say that to me its good next time i will do the best for being understood

Comment: No problem :) As you said just copy & pasting code is not very good, that is why we like all answers to have a bit of explanation why this code fixes the problem, so the ones reading your answer can learn from it.

Comment: youzdev, why wait until next time? Use the edit button.

Comment: next time because on this question they -4 me so they considered me bad explainator